# How to load images dynamically or load only first image in my simple custom gallery?

Tags: jquery, html, image

In this image gallery, if there are a lot of images, browser is loading all of them. How to make browser load only frist images of each gallery, and load other images only if user clicks on pagination numbers? Here is my code:

```
 <div class="photPag">
 <ul class="previewPhoto">
    <li style="display:block;"><a href="/bigImage/1.jpg" data-rel="gallery1">
      <img src="/smallImage/1.jpg" height="200" width="150" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="/bigImage/2.jpg" data-rel="gallery1">
      <img src="/smallImage/2.jpg" height="200" width="150" alt="" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="/bigImage/3.jpg" data-rel="gallery1">
      <img src="/smallImage/3.jpg" height="200" width="150" alt="" /></a></li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="pages">
    <li class="active">1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>                      
 </ul>
</div>

jQuery(".pages li").click (
      function(){
        if  (!jQuery(this).hasClass('active'))
        {
            var anker=jQuery(this).text() -1;
            jQuery(this).parent().find('li').removeClass('active');
            jQuery(this).addClass('active');
            jQuery(this).parent().prev().find('li').css('display','none');
            jQuery(this).parent().prev().find('li').eq(anker).css('display','block');
        }

});
```

Comment: basically what do you want to  do?

Comment: For example I have 50 galleries in one page. Each gallery has 3-7 images. So if user open my page the user's browser will load 150-350 images. I wan't to show only first image in gallery. If user click at pagination <li>2</li> browser should load second image dynamically. So instead of 150-350 images user's browser will load only 50 images. And other images will load only if user click it.

Comment: Do You have any dataBase ..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I edited your question. When you pase code samples, please make sure that their basic indentation level is 4 spaces or 1 tab — that is enough for text to be rendered as code. Anything extra will result in excess spacing before your code that makes it harder to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read about lazy loading. Here's the simplest implementation possible:

```
lazyLoad = function() {
    var img = galleryContainer.find("img:visible");
    if (!img.data("shown")) {
        var dataSrc = img.data("src");
        img.attr("src", dataSrc);
        img.data("shown", true);
    }
}
```

And here's the working demo (really ugly one, but it's only for demonstration purposes).
http://jsfiddle.net/qns1ap60/

In a nutshell:
1. Add some "loading" image as a "src" attribute of every image tag in gallery.
2. Store the real "src" in "data-src" attribute.
3. On image change invoke a lazyLoad function, that will add "data-src" attribute value to "src" one, what will force browser to load a real image.

I think, that you should think about some generic solution for this or even a well known and tested plugin, like [Unveil](http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/)

Comment: To prevent users from seeing a "loading" image too long on some slower connections, you should also think about a buffered loading, that will silently load next/previous image, so your whole application will be more responsive.